# Looping within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to build quite a complex loop in R.

I have a set of data set as an object called `p_int` (`p_int` is peak intensity).
For this example the structure of `p_int` i.e. `str(p_int)` is:

```
num [1:1599]
```

The size of `p_int` can vary i.e. [1:688], [1:1200] etc.

What I'm trying to do with `p_int` is to construct a complex loop to extract the monoisotopic peaks, these are peaks with certain characteristics which will be extracted into a second object: `mono_iso`:

1. search for the first eight sets of data results in `p_int`. Of these eight, find the set of data with the greatest score (this score also needs to be above 50).
2. Once this result has been found, record it into `mono_iso`.
3. The loop will then fix on to this position of where this result is located within the large dataset. From this position it will then skip the next result along the dataset before doing the same for the next set of 8 results.

So something similar to this:

```
16 Results: 100 120 90 66 220 90 70 30 70 100 54 85 310 200 33 41
```

** So, to begin with, the loop would take the first 8 results:

```
100 120 90 66 220 90 70 30
```

**It would then decide which peak is the greatest:

```
220
```

**It would determine whether 220 was greater than 50

```
IF YES:  It would record 220 into "mono_iso"
IF NO: It would move on to the next set of 8 results
```

**220 is greater than 50... so records into mono_iso

The loop would then place it's position at 220 it would then skip the "90" and begin the same thing again for the next set of 8 results beginning at the next data result in line: in this case at the 70:

```
70 30 70 100 54 85 310 200
```

It would then record the "310" value (highest value) and do the same thing again etc etc until the end of the set of data.

Hope this makes perfect sense. If anyone could possibly help me out into making such a loop work with R-script, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Why skip 90? What happens if the peak is the last observation in the batch of 8? Are you sure it is not supposed to continue at "70 100 54 ..."? In my answer below, I've assume you want to process each batch independently.

Comment: My first idea would be using a `while` loop for this (which means that it will be slow and should probably be implemented with Rcpp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
mono_iso <- aggregate(p_int, by=list(group=((seq_along(p_int)-1)%/%8)+1), function(x)ifelse(max(x)>50,max(x),NA))$x
```

This will put `NA` for groups such that `max(...)<=50`. If you want to filter those out, use this:

```
mono_iso <- mono_iso[!is.na(mono_iso)]
```

Comment: Thanks Ferdinand, that's pretty much it!